Xcode 16: invalid absolute path ''
Earlier I was running my iOS project on Xcode 15.4 on macOS Sonoma which is working perfectly fine, when I started using Xcode 16.0 on both macOS Sonoma & Sequoia I facing following compile time error

invalid absolute path ''


Whereas other Xcode projects new/old as working as expected.
I even went to the shell script mentioned in path

I am not able to understand what has been broken in Xcode 16.0 by which it is not able to find the absolute path. This dependency is really important to generate assets & localisations.
Note:

I am using SPM to load all dependencies.
Already cleared derived data & reload all dependencies.
Clean project multiple times,
Restarted system.
Reinstall Command line tools for Xcode 16.0
Updated versions of dependencies.
Used ChatGPT, Gemini to resolve issue.

Nothing worked out. Now I am posting here, Really Appreciate some help.
Thank you

I was also facing the same issue in swiftlint run script phase.
Below steps worked for me:

Clean derived data
Clean Build folder
Quit and restart Xcode
Reset package caches
Most important - Select For install builds only
in Run script phase

Full Run script below:


Thanks @UditS, it worked for running build for simulator & device.
I still see same issue when archiving the build for AppStore distribution. Any idea ?

I was also facing the same issue with XCode 16.
Try replacing SDKROOT=macosx with SDKROOT=(xcrun --sdk macosx --show-sdk-path)
Its working for me.
